# Compare percent in relation to amount

Tags: percentages

I have a six different objects. Each object contain different values for: 'Amount', 'Total', and 'Percentage'.
I want to compare these objects to each other, and see which object "is the best". My first thought was simply to calculate the percentage based on Amount out of Total, and say the object with the highest percentage is the best.

Then I realized that the objects have very different totals, and a simple percentage comparison would be unfair.

These are my objects and their values:

$$\begin{array}{|c|r|r|r|}
\hline
Object & Amount & Total & \% \\
\hline
A & 11,222 & 12,176 & 92.16\% \\
\hline
B & 11,361 & 11,768 & 96.54\% \\
\hline
C & 265 & 610 & 43.44\% \\
\hline
D & 158 & 160 & 98.75\% \\
\hline
\end{array}$$

It seems unfair to compare A (92%) to D (98%), when A has so much more in Total.

**Question:**
Is there a good way to compare all these objects to each other? Perhaps by putting the values into some equation and getting a new value out, which can then be compared (the highest new value = the best)?

Comment: It depends on the meaning of the figures and on what you want to compare. Please clarify.

Comment: You might be interested in this rating/sorting algorithm http://www.evanmiller.org/how-not-to-sort-by-average-rating.html

Comment: @Javi That looks like precisely the thing I need. I'm afraid that equation is way above my head, though. Is there an online tool so I can simply put the numbers in and get the result out?

Comment: I don't know any, but maybe you can't try the code written there in SQL or Excel.